# Statistics Confidence Intervals

Tags: statistics

True or false:

a) The center of a 95% CI for the population mean is a random variable?

d) Out of 100 95% CI for the mean $\mu$, 95 will contain the mean $\mu$?

Answer (score 5):

The assertion (a) is true.  Think about how we produce a $95$ percent confidence interval.  We take a random sample, with the details of size dependent on assumptions about the distribution. Then we perform certain computations to find the center of the confidence interval.

A different random sample will likely produce a somewhat different center, so the center is a function of the results in a random experiment, and is therefore a random variable.

As to (d), one should say it is false.  With probability $0.95$, the CI will contain the mean $\mu$.  If the confidence interval we produced contains $\mu$, call that a "success," our prediction turned out to be right.

If you repeat an experiment $100$ times, and the probability  of success each time is $0.95$, that does not mean that you will *necessarily* get *exactly* $95$ successes.  So (d) is false.  If (d) had said "Out of $1000$ $95$% CI for $\mu$, *approximately* $950$ will contain the mean $\mu$", then it would be true.